# Asp.net webforms c# gridview cell selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I’m working on a webform c# and i have a gridview. I want to select any cell i want in any row or column, instead of having the select button from autogenerateselectbutton that selects all the row.
How can I achieve this? 
Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: Good question? yes